# How to access/assert tuple key values in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

How can I return "True" or "False" if 2 consecutive strings are in a dictionary key that is a tuple/triple?

```
 d = {(1, 'a', 'b') : 2, (4, 'c', 'd'):5}
```

I need an expression like:

```
return 'a', 'b' in d.keys()
```

Comment: It is supposed to check if 2 consecutive strings are in the key, that is - string 'a' followed by string 'b'

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with nested for loops:

```
def myFunc(myDict):
    myKeys = list(myDict.keys())
    for myList in myKeys:
        myPreviousElement = None
        for myElement in myList:
            if myElement == myPreviousElement:
                return True
            myPreviousElement = myElement
    return False

d = {(1, 'a', 'a') : 2, (4, 'c', 'd'):5}
print(myFunc(d)) # True

d = {(1, 'a', 'b') : 2, (4, 'c', 'd'):5}
print(myFunc(d)) # False
```

Then you can customize return values how you prefer

Comment: I think there is a problem with this... if the triple is (‘a’, ‘b’, ‘a’) it give like they are consecutive

Answer (score 1):

You could pair elements for each key in the dictionary and then check if any of those pairs equals your desired result, eg:

```
d = {(1, 'a', 'b') : 2, (4, 'c', 'd'):5}

# Check for existence of any key matching criteria
any(pair == ('a', 'b') for key in d for pair in zip(key, key[1:]))
# True

# Filter out keys/values matching criteria
{k: v for k, v in d.items() if any(p == ('a', 'b') for p in zip(k, k[1:]))}
# {(1, 'a', 'b'): 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work fine

```
for key in d:
        return key[1] == string_1 and key[2] == string_2
```